# webMethods Integratioin Server to Azure Event Hubs directly using webMethods java service

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am trying to send some events from webMethods Integration Server to Azure Event Hub using a java service on webMethods Integration Server. So the webMethods Integration Server is the client here. When I send events using the same java service from my local I am able to send the events successfully to the azure event hub. However when I am trying to send these events from the webMethods Integration Server I am getting the following error.com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.CommunicationException
This is the full stack trace:-
INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.CommunicationException: Connection refused INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:63) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory.onConnectionError(MessagingFactory.java:258) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler.onTransportError(ConnectionHandler.java:179) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:191) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:512) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) INFO | jvm 1 | 2020/04/06 04:45:23 | at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Can anyone help resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are hitting networking issues. Here is two things you can try:

1. Configure firewall and enable outbound connections on ports 5672 and 5671
2. Switch to AMQP over websockets.

Comment: Hi Serkant, 
Thank You so much for your reply.
Could you please elaborate on the above steps .
I need to give explanation before I can request for these configuration.

1.Configure firewall and enable outbound connections on ports 5672 and 5671
Is this to receive the connection object being returned from Azure ?

2.Switch to AMQP over websockets.
Could you please elaborate on this and share the steps to do this?

Comment: You should try bullet 2 first. If it works then there is no need for firewall configuration. Can you point me what Java SDK you are running with? I will provide you instructions on how to enable AMQP over websockets.

Comment: Hi Serkant,
The webMethods Server is running on Java version 1.8.0_202 (52.0)

Comment: I mean the EH SDK. Can you point which release from Maven is being linked? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs

Comment: Hi Serkant,
I dont think we are using maven.

Comment: Sorry, I lost track of this question. In order to switch to AMQP over websockets, add "TransportType=AmqpWebSockets" to you connection string and see if it helps.